# Unable to bind property to WPF label

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to bind the content of a label to the value of a Property in one of my classes. When the value of the Property changes I want it to change the content of the label.

Here is my Location class:

```
public class Location : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private String town;

    public String Town
    {
        get { return town; }
        set 
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(Town);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Town));
    }

    public Location()
    {
      town = "test";
    }
 }
```

Here is the `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="WeatherApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Weather Application" Height="550" Width="850" Loaded="Window_Loaded" IsEnabled="True" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Icon="/WeatherApplication;component/Images/weatherIcon.png">
    <Grid Height="522" Background="#FFE7E7E7">

        <Label Content="{Binding Town, Mode=OneWay}" Name="townLabel" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I doing wrong here that is making it not update the label contents with the value of the Property?

Comment: didn't you forget to actually set your value?

Comment: @Kilazur no, I just omitted that initially to simply code example, have put that back in now..

Comment: OnPropertyChanged("Town");

Comment: @crm: No, you've set your private backing field in the constructor, not the property ("town" vs "Town").

Comment: I mean, as in toadflakz's answer: `town = value` in your set

Comment: Where do you set your `DataContext`?

Comment: This `Location` class is in a separate class library is that helps?

Comment: @Bob. I havent I dont think? What is this?

Comment: [`DataContext`](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) is how you associate your XAML with your ViewModel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need to set the local variable `town`:

```
private String town;
public String Town
{
    get { return town; }
    set 
    {
        town = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Town");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

`DataContext` of `Window` has not been set so it needs to be in order for the `Binding` to work correctly.

XAML:

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WeatherApplication" ....>
  <Window.DataContext>
      <local:Location/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  ....
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext = new Location(); 
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the `DataContext` for the `Window` containing the `Location` class object?

Comment: I haven't, how do I do this?

Comment: Either through XAML or by setting Window.DataContext to your object.

Comment: But on this window I have initialized several Objects. How can I bind one label to Location.Property and another label to Weather.Property?

Comment: They way you have suggested it looks like it is setting a new empty instance of Location and is not using the instance of Location with the properties I need to use, which is initiated in Window_Loaded!?

Comment: Just set the DataContext in Window_Loaded to the actual instance of the class you want to bind to. If you want different Lables to bind to different objects just set the DataContext of the Label instead of the Window.

Comment: I would also strongly suggest you read Kent Boogaart's blog on MVVM - it's one of the best descriptions of the pattern around and if you're working with WPF, you will save yourself a world of trouble using the pattern. http://kentb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html

Answer (score 1):

**First :** you need to assign the value to the private field `town`.

```
public String Town
    {
        get { return town; }
        set 
        {
            town = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Town");
        }
    }
```

**Second :** in the constructor you need to update the public property `Town` not the private field, so the `OnPropertyChanged` can be triggered

```
public Location()
{
   Town = "test";
}
```

**Edit:**

**Third :** Your Xaml don't show any source for the DataBinding, you can set it by, for instance, in the code behind (since you are not following MVVM here) :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    This.DataContext = new Location();
}
```

Comment: and in addition to this: you have to set the DataContext of your window to an instance of your Location class

Comment: @blindmeis indeed ! I assumed that was handled, didn't check his Xaml well though, gonna edit !

Answer (score 0):

It's not raising because

```
public Location()
{
  town = "test"; // You set'd on the field and not the property so it didn't raise
}
```